# Jenkins inject environment variable into local workfolder

Tags: jenkins, cmd, environment-variables

I need to inject an environment var into this line on a jenkins server.

[image]

Where PROJECT_VERSION if the environment var.

I have tried %PROJECT_VERSION%, %%PROJECT_VERSION%%, $PROJECT_VERSION..

the error looks something like this

```
 C:\Jenkins\jobs\testJob\workspace\$PROJECT_VERSION\src' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component.
```

Answer (score -1):

You need the EnvInject plugin installed and activated https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Which plugin is the 'Local Workfolder' sourced from?

Comment: I have the env Inject pluging working and injecting the VAR, its the syntax thats a problem (I added the error)

Comment: local workfolder is under the Source Control Management with a Team Foundation Server selected.

Comment: I'm not so sure you can use environment variables there. What you could do is check it out to a static path (say tmp) and then as a first build step move it to where you want it. This would break scm polling though. Alternatively you could have separate jobs for each of the PROJECT_VERSIONS you need